# Enable/Disable `path_with_escaped_slashes_action` based on path

Tags: envoyproxy

I use envoy as an edge proxy in front of a service, and I want certain paths to use `path_with_escaped_slashes_action` with `REJECT_REQUEST` and some with `KEEP_UNCHANGED`, but as far as my little understanding goes, one can only have one `http_connection_manager`. Is there a way to make this work?